# Test cafe javascript framework - I am getting the action is expected to be an <iframe>

Tags: javascript, iframe, frame, testcafe

I am trying to switch to a  inside a  and using await t.switchToIframe('elementSelector');
And then clicking on an element after this.
But getting error on switch to iframe line as The action element is expected to be an .

What is wrong here

Comment: Please share a simple sample so that we can research this behavior.